# How to add user controls programmatically

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls

I am trying to programmatically add a UserControl every time a button is clicked. The first time it works but after that I can see the number of controls increasing but not being displayed.

```
private void AddRecord()
    {
        StackPanel wrp = (this.Content as Grid).Children[0] as StackPanel;
        wrp.Children.Clear();
        for (int i = 0; i < m_viewModel.RecordTimeConfig.Count; i++)
        {
            wrp.Children.Add(m_viewModel.RecordTimeConfig[i]);
        } 
    }
```

Every time I click the button m_viewModel.RecordTimeConfig is increased.
The stackpanel has no set height and width.

Comment: RecordTimeConfig is an array of UserControls?

Comment: Could it be as simple as `wrp.InvalidateArrange()` or `wrp.InvalidateMeasure()` ?

Comment: Thank you for the reply, it is a list of user controls both wrp.InvalidateArrange() and wrp.InvalidateMeasure() not change anyrhing

Comment: Try to set Width and Height of 'm_viewModel.RecordTimeConfig[i]', m_viewModel.RecordTimeConfig[i].Width=100 etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the problem.

It was due to the size of the user control it was larger than the size of the window.

Thank you all for your help

Answer (score 1):

this is your problem

```
wrp.Children.Clear();
```

You're removing all the controls in your stack panel each time you press the key, so you are adding a new control but you are also removing the one that's already there.

Comment: Thank you for the reply,  No it's not the problem becuase i'm adding the controls all over again the controls inside this stack panel are the users controls m_viewModel.RecordTimeConfig if i'll remove it, it will throw an exception that this control already in use.